# Is there any sun 日 in 昌?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin, character-components

I've been seeing conflicting explanations for this character 昌. Some sources say it comprised of two suns 日, some sources say it comprises of sun and speak 日 meaning flourish, though I don't really see what connection it has to the sun. And then I've seen explanations that it's two 日 speaking mouths, being the original character for sing 唱 and sun is not a component. Which of these is the correct?

Comment: upper 日plus lower 曰。One of the meanings of 昌 is bright. So, it definitely has something to do with sun. Check out this page https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%98%8C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image] | [甲](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)185 [合集19924](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=19924&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[燕](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yan_(state)) 古幣 | [image: 昌] | 108 古幣文編 |
| 戰國・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state)) [璽印](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia)) | [image: 昌] | 959 古璽彙編 |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 昌] | [日甲](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)119 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image: 昌] | [日部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=96) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 昌] |  |

「昌」 (*early morning call*, e.g. to the day's labour) is comprised of semantic 「[日](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=136)」 (*sun*) on top of semantic 「[口](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=39)」 (*mouth*). Such calls would likely be rhythmic or melodious, similar to [bugle calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugle_call), making the interpretation of 「昌」 as the original form of 「唱」 (*to sing*).

Later on, 「口」 was slightly shape-corrupted into 「[甘](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=264)」 (*mouth* 「口」 *with a mark inside*) or 「[曰](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=137)」 (*mouth* 「口」 *with a mark above*). The modern shape inherits 「曰」.

*Flourish* does not appear to have a direct connection to *morning call*, and should be regarded as a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)